# I can't change the color to red in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the color of a `p` tag using JavaScipt (onclick), in w3schools it shows:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}
```

but I don't like the `document.getElementById` thing so I'm wondering how to replace it.

I am trying with

```
function change() {
    document.write(color().style.color = red);
}
```

but it's not working. (Keep in mind I am new to javascript) Thanks. :)

Comment: you don't like ?, in your second function you are not using any ID, it can't work..

Comment: You like `document.write()` over `document.getElementById()`? Also, what is the `color()` function in the second snippet supposed to do?

Comment: You can try use jquery with something like that ; `$("#demo").css("color", "red")`

Comment: @JaxTeller jQuery? To replace a single-line function?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! :) Why don't you like to use `getElementById()`? `document.write()` serves a completery different purpose than `getElementById()`. Also, what is `color()`? Can you provide more detail about that?

Comment: w3school already answered this question....

Comment: @JaxTeller You really shouldn't suggest jQuery to someone who doesn't understand the basics of JavaScript element manipulation yet... It just confuses them even more.

Comment: What do you mean by you don't like? It should be done through document.getElementById() only. It's good practice to have it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` which is quite similar to `document.getElementById` and in your case, it does the same. Note that `document.write` is not the right method this time, because i*t writes text directly to an HTML document* and you cannot use it for changing the colour of an element.

> document.querySelector(element) gets the first element with the given id or
>   class in the parentheses

```js
function myFunction() { document.querySelector("#demo").style.color = "red"; }
```

```css
#demo{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Watch me change</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change color</button>
```

**Reference**

[W3Schools: document.querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)
[Read about what document.write() does](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

Comment: Sidenote: it's `w3schools` as it has no relationship to the actual W3C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `this` keyword.

```
this.style.color = 'red';
```

To change the style of an element, you need a reference to that element which is exactly what `document.getElementById` gives you. There are other methods too but since you are using it as onclick listener, you can make use of the fact that `this` keyword contains the reference to the targeted element.

**Sample Snippet:**

```html
<p onclick="this.style.color='red'">Click this to change color to red</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` accepts a value to output to the `document`

```
 function change() {
   document.write(<div id='demo' style='color: red'>TEXT</div>);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't like JavaScript(document.getElementById) {But Why?}, you could go with some CSS like this:

> The :active selector is used to select and style the active link. A
>   link becomes active when you click on it. The :active selector can be
>   used on all elements, not only links.

```css
p {color: blue;cursor: pointer;}

p:active {color: red}
```

```html
<p> I change color when clicked </p>
```